# C time program (NTP) doesn't bind the socket

Tags: c, sockets, ntp

I've written a little program that should get the time from a SNTP server. Got a problem that the program doesn't bind the socket. I read RFC 2030, and i'm doing everything as it explained, using UDP, port 123. Also double checked that UDP doesn't need a connect only a bind. I don't see my fault, and the debugger isn't giving me usefull information.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib" )
#define BUFFSIZE 1024

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int sockfd;
    char msg[48];
    unsigned long buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    int rv;
    int counter = 0;
    int numbytes;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    for(counter = 0; counter < 48; counter++)
        msg[counter] = 0;

    msg[0] = 11; //1 byte = 3 first flags set in binary: 00 001 011
    msg[1] = 0;
    msg[2] = 6;
    msg[3] = 1;
    msg[12] = 76;
    msg[13] = 79;
    msg[14] = 67;
    msg[15] = 76;


    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; // Use UDP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo("ntp.belnet.be", "123", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }
    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to create the socket\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            closesocket(sockfd);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to bind socket\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    //zenden en vragen naar de tijd
    if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0,p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
        perror("Couldn't send the message.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr_size = sizeof their_addr;
    if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, 12 * sizeof(buffer[0]) , 0,(struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size))== -1) {
        perror("Failed Receive");
        exit(1);
    }

    closesocket(sockfd); //close the socket
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: already found the problem here is the solution:

```
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n");
    exit(1);
}

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; // Use UDP

if ((rv = getaddrinfo("ntp.belnet.be", "123", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
}
// loop door al de resultaten en maak de socket
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create the socket\n");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
//zenden en vragen naar de tijd
if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, msg, 48, 0,p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
    perror("Couldn't send the message.\n");
    exit(1);
}
addr_size = sizeof their_addr;
if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, 48 , 0,(struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size))== -1) {
    perror("Failed Receive");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Call `perror()` after the failed `bind()`. What does it print?

Comment: bind() is used to set the address and port of your side of the conversation.  This looks like you're trying to bind to the address to which you intend to send packets?  Take the bind out and just use sendto() if you don't care what your source port is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n");
    exit(1);
}

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; // Use UDP

if ((rv = getaddrinfo("ntp.belnet.be", "123", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
}
// loop door al de resultaten en maak de socket
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create the socket\n");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
//zenden en vragen naar de tijd
if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, msg, 48, 0,p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
    perror("Couldn't send the message.\n");
    exit(1);
}
addr_size = sizeof their_addr;
if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, 48 , 0,(struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size))== -1) {
    perror("Failed Receive");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: -1. do you expect people to compare the two codes to figure out what you did?